# Get return value of `include` in jade template

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, pug

What I basically try to accomplish is to re-use jade partials/templates when getting data through a socket connection. Non working example:

```
socket.on('company_created', function(company) {
  var html = include _company;
  $('#companies ul').append(html);
});
```

Normally I had to create a new `li` and set the content like so (which is working as expected):

```
$('#companies ul').append($('<li>').text(company.name));
```

This is okay for a simple list, but if I had complexer list and stuff, this could get messy pretty quick, plus I had to write plain HTML again, so I figured re-using my already existing jade templates with all their goodness would be awesome, but had not luck, yet.

Any clue?

PS: Please do not tell my to use Ember, Backbone, Derby, Meteor, Angular or whatsoever.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your jade sources to JS with `jade.compile`. Then include these sources in the client-side javascript, include jade's `runtime.min.js`, and refer to your jade templates as to normal JS functions in your client-side code.

For example,

**server.js**

```
app.get('/templates/:template.js', function (req, res) {
    var template = req.params.template;
    response.end([
        "window.templates = window.templates || {};",
        "window.templates[\"" + template + "\"] = " + jade.compile(template + ".jade", { client: true; });
    ].join("\r\n"));
});
```

**client.js**

```
$(function() { $("#placeholder").html(window.templates["content"]({user: "Daniel" })); });
```

**content.jade**

```
h1: Hello #{user}!
```

**index.jade**

```
!!!
html
    head
        script(src='/lib/jquery/jquery.js')
        script(src='/lib/jade/runtime.min.js')
        script(src='/templates/content.js')
        script(src='/scripts/client.js')
    body
        #placeholder
```

Note that the code above might be syntactically incorrect and is provided solely to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Can you give a quick example, please? I don't really get the last part with "refer as normal functions". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we have a build step that compiles them to functions sort of like penartur mentioned. I dont use extend or include (which dont work on the client anyway ATM), but personally I find we have absolutely no need for that on the client at all since the DOM provides all the separation we need.